# How to set state and re render a ModalRoute

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I have Search Modal popup where the user can search and get results based on their search. However, since the class extends ModalRoute and not a StatefulWidget, calling setState does not re-render the build and the search results do no appear on the  screen. Is there a way to update the state or re-render the screen without having to convert the class to a StatefulWidfet?

```
class JobSerachModal extends ModalRoute {
  List<dynamic>? searchResults;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 250);

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => false;

  @override
  Color get barrierColor => Colors.black;

  @override
  String? get barrierLabel => null;

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;


  getSearch(String query) async {
    var result = await SearchService().getAllPaged(query: query);
    setState(() {
      searchResults = result;
    });
  }

  _onSearchChanged(String query) {
    getSearch(query);
  }

  @override
  Widget buildPage(
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  ) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: _onSearchChanged,
                      autofocus: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                      child: const Text('Cancel'))
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              ...searchResults.map(
                (search) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(search.title),
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```